# Discord.js v14 how to handle button interactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js, interaction

I'm trying to make a help command for my discord bot with menus and buttons, but I encountered multiple problems:

**I don't know how to handle the "Interaction failed" text showing up when I click a button even tho the button responded.**

How can I use the ***deferUpdate()*** for buttons in the latest discord.js? If I should use collectors, where should I put the collector? I read the official docs but still don't understand how to use it.

I also tried not to use collectors or await, but I always get "Interaction has been acknowledged" the second time I use the help command.

Furthermore, I'm always getting errors like Invalid Body Form, Unknown interaction, or Interaction has already been acknowledged when clicking the buttons.

Here's the part of my code handling the interaction:

```
message.channel.send({
            embeds: [page1], components:[row]
        }).then((msg) => {
            let times = 0
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                times += 1;
                if(times === 15){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                }
            }, 1000); 
            client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
                if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

                if(interaction.customId == 'next'){
                    curPage += 1
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    if(curPage == maxPage){
                        nextBtn.setDisabled(true)
                        lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    }
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'previous'){
                    curPage -= 1
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    if(curPage == 1){
                        previousBtn.setDisabled(true)
                        firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    }
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'first'){
                    curPage = 1
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'last'){
                    curPage = maxPage
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)

                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                }

                const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 3500 });

                collector.on('collect', async i => {
                    if(i.user.id === interaction.user.id){
                        if (interaction.isButton()) {
                            interaction.deferUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                });

                collector.on('end', collected => {console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`); collector.stop()});
            });
        })
    },
```

**Full code of the help command:**

```
help: function (message, client) {
        let categories = listCmds.getCates();
        let maxPage = 2;
        let curPage = 1;
        let funCmds = listCmds.getCmds(listCmds.liCmds.categories.FUN)

        let row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                firstBtn = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('first')
                    .setLabel('First page')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
                    .setDisabled(true)
            )
            .addComponents(
                previousBtn = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('previous')
                    .setLabel('<<')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            )
            .addComponents(
                nextBtn = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('next')
                    .setLabel('>>')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
            )
            .addComponents(
                lastBtn = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('last')
                    .setLabel('Last page')
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)
            )
        let page1 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({ name: 'Help menu', iconURL: 'https://i.postimg.cc/rwXj33rv/sonnnn.png' })
            .setTitle(`${categories[0]}`)
            .setColor([144, 238, 144])
            .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVUWJ4CIuE9e7hXNiKOjg5w/featured')
            .addFields(
                { name: funCmds[0][0], value: funCmds[0][1]},
                { name: funCmds[1][0], value: funCmds[1][1]},
                { name: funCmds[2][0], value: funCmds[2][1]},
                { name: funCmds[3][0], value: funCmds[3][1]},
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `Page 1/${maxPage}. If you find any bugs, please report at https://discord.gg/wRtZ6fRhZC.`})

        let page2 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({ name: 'Help menu', iconURL: 'https://i.postimg.cc/rwXj33rv/sonnnn.png' })
            .setTitle(`This is the end!`)
            .setColor([144, 238, 144])
            .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVUWJ4CIuE9e7hXNiKOjg5w/featured')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: 'More categories of commands coming soon!',
                    value: ':)',
                    inline: true
                },
            )
            .setFooter({ text: `Page 2/${maxPage}. If you find any bugs, please report at https://discord.gg/wRtZ6fRhZC.`})

        let pages = [page1, page2]

        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [page1], components:[row]
        }).then((msg) => {
            let times = 0
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                times += 1;
                if(times === 15){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                }
            }, 1000); 
            client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
                if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

                if(interaction.customId == 'next'){
                    curPage += 1
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    if(curPage == maxPage){
                        nextBtn.setDisabled(true)
                        lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    }
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'previous'){
                    curPage -= 1
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    if(curPage == 1){
                        previousBtn.setDisabled(true)
                        firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    }
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'first'){
                    curPage = 1
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                } else if(interaction.customId == 'last'){
                    curPage = maxPage
                    firstBtn.setDisabled(false)
                    lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    nextBtn.setDisabled(true)
                    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)

                    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
                }

                const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 3500 });

                collector.on('collect', async i => {
                    if(i.user.id === interaction.user.id){
                        if (interaction.isButton()) {
                            interaction.deferUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                });

                collector.on('end', collected => {console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`); collector.stop()});
            });
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle buttons inside your `collector`, and defer the `collector`'s buttons, not the interaction itself.

So remove completely the `client.on` part, and do something like this:

```
// should definitely increase the time in your collector.
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 3500 });

collector.on('collect', async i => {
  // check if the author triggered the interaction
  if(i.member.id != interaction.user.id) {
    return i.reply({ content: `This interaction is not for you`, ephemeral: true})
  }

  if(i.customId == 'next') {
    // defer the interaction
    await i.deferUpdate();

    curPage += 1
    firstBtn.setDisabled(false)
    previousBtn.setDisabled(false)
    nextBtn.setDisabled(false)

    if(curPage == maxPage){
      nextBtn.setDisabled(true)
      lastBtn.setDisabled(true)
    }
    msg.edit({embeds: [pages[curPage-1]], components:[row]})
  }

  if(i.customId == 'previous') {
    // defer update
    await i.deferUpdate();

   // Rest of your code
 }

 // and so on

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a question: In the "const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector..." line, the interaction is not defined. Where and how can I define it?

Comment: This is not a slash command right? If so, instead of `interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector` use `message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector`

Comment: `client.on('interactionCreate')` can be used for buttons as well which is why the [`interaction.isButton()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=isButton) type guard and a [`ButtonInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction) even exists

Comment: @Crytek1012 I'm getting this error every second time I run the help command, and I can't figure out how to fix it :( DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.

Comment: @Caladan You're right! But I don't know how to handle the "Interaction Failed" or deferring the interaction using client.on('interactionCreate') because I'm always getting errors :( How to defer the button interaction using this interaction handling method?

Comment: Do we 100% always need a collector to handle button interactions in any cases?

Comment: No, actually that was a mistake on my side. You can also use `client.on("interactionCreate")`, but for what you're trying to acheive, a `collector` is simply a better fit.

Comment: @Crytek1012 Oh ok, thx a lot! I have a last problem: I'm always getting this error "DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged." every second time I call the command and click a button. I tried some methods I found on Google, but they all didn't work for me. How can we fix this?

Comment: That happens because your buttons have the same custom ID. In order to avoid that, the best way is to create your collector on a `message` instead of the channel.
Store the embed you want to send in a variable:
`const MSG = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [page1], components:[row] });`
Then, create the collector on that message:
`const collector = MSG.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 3500 });`

Comment: You're welcome! If you find this solution good enough, despite its negative count, please mark it as accepted :D